# Woocommerce V3 Api Remove Order Limitation of 10

Tags: json, api, woocommerce

I am trying to import all the orders through the API (6,500 pieces), but I noticed that the API only makes 10 queries. By adjusting the link domain/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?per_page=100 I can query 100 orders, but I can't get it to query all orders with one call. Is this possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get all 6500 orders at once, and the API is limited at a maximum of 100 orders per call. The only way of solving this is by making a loop and do multiple calls. However there are [2 HTTP headers](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#pagination) that might help you. `X-WP-Total` and `X-WP-TotalPages`.

Another solution would be to create your own Wordpress plugin, which adds a new endpoint, and that way you get all your orders

Comment: There are two urls in the link. Can I also expand this to e.g. 500 to get all.

Or how can I query 100 and then the next 100 from page 2 and so on.

Thanks already

Comment: @p_e_88 there is no default way how you can expand it to 500 for example. You could loop through it on the client side (if you're using any programming language). I edited the post for another solution